# I'm trying to make a script that saves all images on a website to a folder

Tags: powershell

I want to be prompted for the link, and then it downloads all the image files into a folder, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

I have tried using a csv file, which I imported, but when trying to import, it claims that it's a null value, so instead I decided to ditch the csv approach, and try something else. But "?" is where I'm having trouble, I want it to take all the values in the $images variable separately and run a sort of export command on each value, but I'm not sure how to do it, here's the script so far:

```
$Url = Read-host "Paste page url"
$OutputPath = ".\img-grab"

$iwr = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url
$images = (($iwr.Images | Format-Table -Property 'src' -HideTableHeaders | Out-String).Trim())

$images | ?

Write-Host "Downloading all images from $Url to $OutputPath"
```

An example of the data in the $images variable:

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/745629067874017280/1472662609/1500x500
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1036953347943743488/1dbRCWDq_400x400.jpg
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1036953347943743488/1dbRCWDq_normal.jpg
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Create web scraping tool in Powershell](https://www.business.com/articles/create-web-scraping-tool-in-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

The `-OutFile` param will probaby do what you're after.

More information: [Invoke-WebRequest documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)